# Making Bootable USB From DVD using Command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-7, usb, boot

Is there any way to create a boot-able USB from a windows DVD via command line?
It is accepted using third party application which accepts command line arguments.
I searched internet but did not found any way.

Comment: this may better fit to SuperUser, but here is a link to make a bootable USB drive using bootsect.exe http://www.bjorn3d.com/2009/07/making-an-ntfs-usb-boot-disk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the program diskpart which is included in windows.

You need the following steps:

```
SELECT DISK <DRIVE NUMBER>
CLEAN
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
SELECT PARTITION 1
ACTIVE
FORMAT FS=NTFS QUICK
ASSIGN
EXIT
```

save them in a txt file. Find out the drive number using "LIST DISK"
You can then call diskpart with the /s parameter and give the saved textfile as a script.
Afterwards you can copy the content of the dvd over.

Now as to really do this programmatically: 
The main difficulty would be selecting the correct drive number in case it may vary.

The main problem however is that this is a pretty dangerous operation. If you select the wrong disk (as stated those drives are selected by number not even by their drive letter) instead of your usb drive you might format a partition of your harddrive. I would personally not really fully automate the task but rather do it by hand.